# php/html: Check if typed date matches current date

Tags: php, html

I created a program that allows u to type in the date and then when u click submit it should say whether the date u typed matches the CURRENT DATE (so the date updates itself) anyways, i am not so good at php and this is what i could make: whats the problem and can u demonstrate how to fix it.

```
<?php
session_start();
$EntryError="";
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $entrydate = "";
        $errorOccured = false;

        if (isset($_POST['tsmdate'])){
            $entrydate = trim($_POST['tsmdate']);
            if (strlen($entrydate) == 0){
                $EntryError = "date is missing";
                $errorOccured = true;
            }
        }
        else{
            $EntryError = "date is missing";
        }
    }

$presentDate=date('Y-m-d');
    if($date==$presentDate)
    {
        echo "same date";
    }
    else{
        echo "different date";
    }
    ?>
    <html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form name="dates" id="dates" method="POST" action="">
<table cellpadding="5" border="0" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3" align="center">
                <h1> select dates </h1>
                </td>
            </tr>

        <tr>
                <td width="30%" align="right">
                    <label for="tsmdate">Entry date </label>
                </td>
                <td align="left">
                    <input type="date" name="tsmdate" id="tsmdate" required="required">
                </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
                <td colspan="2" align="center">
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="dates">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </form>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are comparing dates outside of the `isset($_POST['submit'])` condition.
Try this :

```
<?php
session_start();
$EntryError="";
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $entrydate = "";
    $errorOccured = false;

    if (isset($_POST['tsmdate'])){
        $entrydate = trim($_POST['tsmdate']);
        if (strlen($entrydate) == 0){
            $EntryError = "date is missing";
            $errorOccured = true;
        }
      else{
        $presentDate=date('Y-m-d');
           if(strtotime($entrydate) == strtotime($presentDate))
            {
              echo "same date";
           }
          else{
             echo "different date";
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        $EntryError = "date is missing";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function strtorime() in C:\xamppp\htdocs\cpu5001\timers.php on line 16 .. I am getting this error

Comment: @DavidAdam there is a typo in the name of function. You could really have checked that out rather than pasting the error message back without any own investigation!

Comment: @DavidAdam : yes that' a mistake . it should be `strtotime`. @Shadow : thanks for looking into it.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code.

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if(isset($_POST['tsmdate'])){
        $entrydate = trim($_POST['tsmdate']);
        if($entrydate == date('Y-m-d')){
           echo "Same Date";
        }
        else{
          echo "Different Date";
        }
   }
else{
    echo "Date is missing";
}
}
?>

<html>
    <body>
        <form name="dates" id="dates" method="POST" action="">
            <table cellpadding="5" border="0" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3" align="center">
                    <h1> select dates </h1>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td width="30%" align="right">
                        <label for="tsmdate">Entry date </label>
                    </td>
                    <td align="left">
                        <input type="date" name="tsmdate" id="tsmdate" required="required">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" align="center">
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="dates">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
       </form>
     </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing the wrong variable. You declared the entered date as $entryDate and then compared $date with the $presentDate

```
if($date==$presentDate)
```

To fix the problem you just use the variable that you declared for the entered date

```
if($entryDate==$presentDate)
```

And that should fix it.